# Deep linking not working in facebook and twitter

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am using deep linking feature in my app for facebook and twitter. Earlier the below lines in the manifest file used to give me option to open a link in the app, but presently it is redirecting to the browser. Below is my manifest

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/prefis"
                android:scheme="https" />

        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I have updated my both facebook and twitter app. After that i am facing this issue

Answer (score -1):

Check the url in browser and add deeplink in accordance with tutorial in your app
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#adding-filters

Comment: I have implemented this in accordance to the link. It was working fine untill i updated my facebook